# Unable to unlock file for editing in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode

For some reason 2 of my files got locked and when I click the little lock icon in the upper right corner of the window it asks me if I would like to unlock, and doing so results in a "The file xxxx.h could not be unlocked" (Unlocking failed for an unknown reason). I have tried to restart Xcode, also tried to restart my machine with no help.

I am also unable to edit the files using BBEdit, I get the error "You do not have sufficient privileges to perform this operation (MacOS Error code: -5000)".

I'm running OS X Lion with Xcode 4.

Very strange as I have not made any changes to my system prior to this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you manually unlock the file in the Finder using Get Info?

Comment: Yes, I am able to do that. I have set all the permissions to Read & Write for everyone for this particular file. I am also able to change the filename, but editing the contents results in this error.

Comment: Try copying the file, deleting the original, and renaming the copy to match the original.

Comment: I have also tried to restore to a time machine backup front before the problem, I have also tried to fix permissions on my drive. Time to do a complete restore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the file in any text editor. If the contents isn't text based you'll see a lot of gibberish. Ignore this, copy the contents. Open up a new text file. Paste the contents and save over the old file. This will copy just the contents of the file and ignore permissions.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the reply. I read this post too late. I just did a restore, going back to 10.6 as I get a lot of crashes with Xcode and 10.7. If it does not resolve the issue, I will try your method.

Comment: Reformat didn't help, but Xcode 4 runs much better in 10.6 (for me). Anyway, pasting contents to new file worked perfectly. Thanks Peter for the answer. Any idea how this could have happened?

Comment: @ngoan When  you're copying the file like that, you're solely copying the *contents* rather than the metadata, which includes permissions and locking and what not. Fixes a lot of tricky situations.

Answer (score 6):

What you're dealing with here is an ACL issue.  If you ls -l the directory you'll see a little + on the end of the permission string:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 4 eekyou  staff  136 May  6  2011 eekyou.xcuserdatad
```

You can easily strip these off like so (in your project directory:

```
sudo chmod -R -E ./*
```

Hope this helps.

=]

Comment: Actually, shouldn't this be `sudo chmod -R -N ./*` ?

Answer (score 2):

The [@eecue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481180/eecue) answer didn't help me. I user another Terminal command for complete removal of all ACL permissions:

> sudo chmod -RN ./*

Answer (score 0):

First check if the file is opened/locked by another program or user.

If it is not, the program probably crashed and failed to remove the flag, lookup the file and check with CMD+i if it is locked.

If it is not, permissions are probably wrong, so check the permission in the CMD+i dialog at the bottom, and apply them to everything in the enclosing folder (a .xcproject is a directory).

If this **still** doesn't work (like for me), there is a simple command line to unlock all files in a folder. ONLY do this if all the above steps have been checked / taken.

```
sudo chflags -R nouchg /Users/username/Development/GIT/MyProject
```

Replacing the project folder with your own project folder of course.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to take ownership of the folder in which you wish to save your project.  To do so, open up the console.  Then type `sudo chown $USER /path/to/your/project`.