# The file “project.pbxproj” could not be unlocked in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, locked-files

Due to some reason some of files were locked in xcode, which i resolved through the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19194547/5698871) solution.

but even after that i keep getting this error

```
****The file “project.pbxproj” could not be unlocked.**
Could not add write permission to the file because you do not own it. Try modifying the permissions of the file in the Finder or Terminal.**
```

I have also tried unlocking it through above method and it is not working, also i'm not even able to close the project and when i force close it, next time all the previous changes are gone.

Answer (score 4):

Permission problem Try

```
sudo Chmod 777 .
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Could not add write permission to the file because you do not own it"

This means that the project was created by a **different user**. Log as that user, or if you cannot, create a "test.txt" file next to the file you can't unlock.

Open Terminal, go to the folder where the project resides, and run a command such as

```
ls -la test.txt project.pbxproj
```

You should see a list such as:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 dakkar users  434 Nov 23 12:17 project.pbxproj
-rw-r--r--  1 lserni users    1 Nov 25 00:14 test.txt
```

Now, the "-rw-r--r--" is the permission. You just created test.txt, so those are the correct permissions from the GUI. r counts for 4, w counts for 2, x counts for one; rw-r--r-- is therefore 6,4,4. In the example, project.pbxproj is 6,6,4.

So the two commands you need are

```
sudo chown lserni:users project.pbxproj  # To set ownership
sudo chmod 644 project.pbxproj           # To set permissions
```

If you are in the project directory **and are absolutely, utterly, deadly sure** that nothing there or in its subdirectories should belong to anyone but you, then you can mass-change ownership of the directory, its subdirectories and all they contain:

```
sudo chown lserni:users -R .
```

If you do the above in the wrong directory (not yours, not a project directory, etc.), the -R (recursive) flag is a recipe for disaster, so be careful.

Just in case, remember that **directories** must have all x's set, so what is 644 for a file would become 755 for a directory.

When finished, you can delete the example file 'test.txt' - actually you can do that as soon as you have written down what the correct ownership and permissions should be.