# Cannot unlock "UITabBarController.h" for editing

Tags: swift, xcode

I need to change the class of `UITabBarController` to a custom one. But Xcode won't allow me to do that. It's saying:

> **The file “UITabBarController.h” could not be unlocked.**
>
> Could not add write permission to the file because you do not own it. Try modifying the permissions of the file in the Finder or Terminal.

I have set the permissions to read and write to the folder in Finder (I also have "Apply to enclosed items" ref [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574543/myproject-is-locked-for-editing-and-you-may-not-be-able-to-save-your-changes.)).

Does anyone have some idea of what else I can try?

Comment: How do you want to change `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you need to do is subclass a `UITabBarController` and then use this instead.

Note that you can **override** `UITabBarController` methods and properties in this subclass as you need.

Apple doesn't allow you to modify their classes as part of `UIKit`, unlike other third party frameworks.