# Xcode: The file “UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate” could not be unlocked

Tags: xcode

I am new in IOS programming. I learn it from designcode.io .   I download the playground file from the website. But when I start to edit it. It will show "The file “UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate” could not be unlocked." ,and "The document"Designcode-Design playground "could not be saved You don't have permission". It is the screen shot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10eB2.png)

and

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Zqh.png)

I have set my user permissions to read and write. But it can't solve this problem. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the same error in my Swift playgrounds on Xcode 10 thru 11.2 beta

Answer (score 0):

I found your answer here:
[myProject is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574543/myproject-is-locked-for-editing-and-you-may-not-be-able-to-save-your-changes)

You can edit setting via `Get Info` then change custom access.

If you still not able to edit it, maybe you can copy the playground file to another folder that you have access to read/write.