# Xcode project files locked for editing, even with folder sharing and permission settings

Tags: xcode, file-permissions

Read & write permissions set:

[image: Read & write permissions set]

Still it shows lock symbol:

[image: Still it shows lock symbol]

See the above images. I've done those permission settings for my project folder. And ensured this setting should apply to underlying folders. Clicked that three dot and selected apply to enclosing folder. And I've also tried with all permutations and combinations of restarting, logging out and restarting, launching project afresh... all of that, but none of this made any changes. Still it shows that locked symbol if I try to drag any object at main.storyboard. Please any one find the solution for this. Eagerly waiting for answers.

Below are version details:

Xcode version : 12.4

MacOS version : Big Sur 11.2

Machine using : MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch)

Make          : Intel made

Comment: Did you tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19194547/14733292

Comment: @RajaKishan sir, I've done all that. Please read my question once again.