# “App Workspace” is locked in Xcode after moving from TimeMachine backup

Tags: macos

I moved a folder back to my Mac via TimeMachine. But I have issues opening an Xcode project.

> “App Workspace” is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your changes. Do you want to unlock it?"

There I click "Unlock", but that results in:

> "The file “my-username.xcuserdatad” could not be unlocked."

> "The file “UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate” could not be unlocked."

I already [tried resetting the rights to the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19194547/1469734). Tried also another Macs (macOS Monterey and also Big Sur) . Still not working.