# Other Linker Flags cannot set to -ObjC

Tags: ios, xcode, build-settings

I am having trouble setting Other Linkers Flags to -ObjC in Xcode. I am trying to add Admob into my app. The issue is that the setting is simply not there. The Other Linker Flags tab is there, but there is nothing beside it. Furthermore, all the other tabs are uneditable.[image: There's simply nothing]

Comment: Did you try to click the little triangle to the left of it?

Comment: @Mike it shows Debug and Release like the one below it

Comment: So when you double click that row in the target column, you cannot enter text?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes. And StackOverflow force me to write more characters for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have accidentally made the XCode project becomes "Read Only".

I hope you have a backup of the project. I have faced it once long ago, I didn't know how to fix that during that time. I used the backup project as a replacement.

I found some resources that might help you to "unlock" the project file:-

[myProject is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574543/myproject-is-locked-for-editing-and-you-may-not-be-able-to-save-your-changes)

[Unable to unlock file for editing in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139780/unable-to-unlock-file-for-editing-in-xcode-4)

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2300074?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: What happens when the project became "Read Only"? I can still edit my code and storyboard and still save them without any problem.

Comment: Yes, you can edit everything else without much problem, same situation like mine. I could not edit the project settings because the project file **.xcodeproj** was "Read Only". I didn't know what I did wrong during that time as well, so, I was forced to use a backup project.

Comment: I have found out the source of the problem. You need to double click below the "PSLE Aggregate Calculator" tab and set the settings from there. Looks like I'm still not familiar enough with Xcode. Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: I hope that you can solve the issue now. No problem. ;)